# Does Primefaces allow poll tag in composite component?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Does Primefaces allow poll tag in "composite component"?

A simple example like this will work in the main template.xhtml...

```
            <h:form id="formm">
              <p:poll id="pol" interval="5" update="currDate" process="@this"/>
              <h:inputText id="currDate" value="#{backingBean.stringValue}"/>
            </h:form>
```

But when included in a "composite component" it no longer updates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <cc:interface/>
    <cc:implementation>
            <h:form id="formm">
              <p:poll id="pol" interval="5" update="currDate" process="@this"/>
              <h:inputText id="currDate" value="#{backingBean.stringValue}"/>
            </h:form>   
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Is the POLL tag supported in a "composite component"?

Comment: Is there another page that is using your composite component?

Comment: Nope, I've got one composite component and one main page that uses it.

Comment: Can you post your main page xhtml that is using your composite component template?